# Where does the sum current of the three currents flow?

Tags: current, delta, star

In the following star and delta connections, if each individual current enters via Phases R, Y and B, where does the sum of the three currents (that is Ia+Ib+Ic) flow after meeting at the common point of the three phases?

Moreover, in such types of connections, across which terminals is a load connected to these types of systems to draw current/power for its operation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The sum of the currents is zero.

Comment: Okay but if I were to keep an ammeter, I can individually measure the value of the three currents right? So how exactly does it become zero? And if the sum is zero, how can I connect a load to the output and draw power from this type of connection?

Comment: remember this is three-phase AC. If you know *complex currents* already, it's really trivial, just write down the currents as complex numbers and add them. Also, get better material: the material you use was made by someone who uses the inductor symbol for resistors, and that's plain wrong (assuming that's what they wanted to show and this isn't about electrical motors. If it's about motors, you need to learn a lot now – start with complex currents.).

Comment: You especially need better learning material if the material you're reading now doesn't explain what happens right after it showed this picture.

Comment: Oh okay. Could you please provide me with some links that you already know of? Would be much appreciated

Comment: Install three ammeters.  One of the measured instantaneous currents is 0.5A, another is 1.75A, and the third is -2..25.   Add these up.  Isn't it zero?  Not difficult  ...unless you believe that the little arrows show the polarity of current.  They do not. They show how to connect your ammeters (placed in series with the three wires, with the ammeter negative terminals towards the coils.)   In other words, if two of the currents are negative, the third will always be positive.   During an AC cycle those little arrows never change (because you're not randomly swapping the ammeter leads around!)

Comment: If you add two sinusoidal currents, the sum will be zero if they're of equal magnitude but have a 180 degree phase difference. if you add three sinusoidal currents, the sum will be zero if they're of equal magnitude but each has a 120 degree phase difference wrt the other two.

Answer (score 1):

> if each individual current enters via Phases R, Y and B, where does
>   the sum of the three currents (that is Ia+Ib+Ic) flow after meeting at
>   the common point of the three phases?

The "sum" current has to be zero because it can't flow anywhere.

> if I were to keep an ammeter, I can individually measure the value of
>   the three currents right? So how exactly does it become zero?

Your ammeter doesn't account for the fact that the three currents have a phase relationship that means they cancel out. Individually they can be measured but I_red = -(I_yellow + I_blue)

Or, I_red + I_yellow + I_blue = 0

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. Three-phase currents sum to zero.*

1. Here we can see that the black and blue phases are at 0.5 of max current and positive. Meanwhile, red is at -1 of max current. They sum to zero.
2. Here we see that black is at +1 while red and blue are at -0.5. They sum to zero.
3. Here we see that blue is at zero. Red is at \$ +\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \$ max current while black is at \$ -\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \$. They sum to zero.

The sum to zero will apply at any point along the time axis if you care to do the calculations.

---

From the comments:

> Ok so if the sum of the currents is zero at the meeting point, how does one draw current from this system to power their load?

There is nothing in your question to indicate whether the circuit represents a generator or a load other than the current direction which suggests that the device is consuming current. In any case, it doesn't matter.

Current flows in a circuit. Current in or out of any branch must find its return through the other two. That's what my Figure 1 is demonstrating.

> Moreover, is the sum of currents = 0 only at the neutral/ common point of the three phases?

There is no other point in your circuit where the currents are summed.

If, however, you run the three conductors through a current clamp meter you will have a reading of zero as the currents in one direction must balance those in the opposite direction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSnAVK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Typical three-phase inverter setup.*

Power flows from the battery, to the inverter where it is converted to three-phase AC and from there to the three-phase load.

Comment: importantly, because of Kirchoff's current law, even if the currents are unbalanced (due to the load being unbalanced) they are still forced to sum to zero.

Comment: Ok so if the sum of the currents is zero at the meeting point, how does one draw current from this system to power their load?

Comment: Moreover, is the sum of currents = 0 only at the neutral/ common point of the three phases?

Comment: See the updates.

Comment: Ah okay. And across which terminals will I connect the load because all I see in my figure are the three input terminals. Is there another set of three output terminals that the diagram isn't showing?

Comment: What load? What input terminals? What output terminals? What are you connecting to what? Your question shows a generic three-phase star (wye) device and a three-phase delta device. It could be a generator, a motor, a heater, the primaries or secondaries of a transformer. Your question needs an edit to fix it.

Comment: Oh okay. Sorry for the ambiguity. To clarify, what if the three terminals through which the current enters are the input terminals. Something like connecting the output of a dc-ac inverter to these three phases. So if I were to draw an output AC, where would I connect the load?

Comment: You can connect a single-phase load between any two phases, or between a phase and neutral.  Here in 120-volt land, we would get 120 volts from phase to neutral, or 208 volts between phases.  You would connect a three-phase load to all three phases, but not to neutral.

Comment: "*...  what if the three terminals through which the current enters are the input terminals. ... So if I were to draw an output AC, where would I connect the load?*" If they are input terminals then they **are** the load. You are asking a series of confused questions about DC, inverters and three-phase. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm learning about converters and inverters and it looks like I messed up somewhere in my understanding of this concept. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: See Figure 2, etc.